# Maximum number of triangles with area 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

We have n dots on a plane such that no three of them are in the same line. Prove that the number of triangles with area 1 that are made by connecting three of these dots is less than or equal to $\frac{3}{2}(n^2-n)$

I got this far:

Every rectangle can make at most four triangles. So using induction, if we look for the maximum number of rectangles with area 2 that can be made by adding one dot to the plane, we can multiply that by four and find the maximum number added triangles and hopefully complete our proof. Finding rectangles must be easier. But I don't know how to find the maximum number of rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick two points $A,B$. Then any point $C$ such that the area of $ABC$ (in either orientation) is $1$ must be one one of two parallel lines to $AB$. Hence each pair $(A,B)$ can be completeted to an area-1-triangle in at most four ways. This gives us $4\cdot {n\choose 2}$ candidate triangles - but each triangle is counted thrice (once per side). Thus the total number of such triangles is at most
$$\frac13\cdot 4\cdot {n\choose 2}=\frac23(n^2-n).$$

Comment: brilliant proof! Thank you